# cannot get $_POST variable value when HTML form is isset

Tags: php, html, forms, post

i want to get the value of a text input 'name="quantity"' when my html form is isset using $_POST , the problem is everytime i submit the form i cannot get it's value ! 
HTML :

```
<form method="POST" name="updateform">
<!-- the input text that i want to get it's value when the form is isset -->
 <input type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $row['quantite'] ?>" size="1" class="form-control" />
<!-- the input text that i want to get it's value when the form is isset -->
<a type="submit" name="updateu" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Update" class="btn btn-primary" href='cart.php?id=<?php echo $getid ?>&upt=<?php echo $row['idproduit']; ?>' ><i class="fa fa-clone"></i></a>
                     </form>
```

PHP :

```
//update commande
           if (isset($_POST['updateform'])) {

              $mdf = $_POST['quantity'];
              echo $mdf;
           }else{
            echo "form not isset()";
           }
        //update commande
```

it's showing "form not isset"

any solutions please , and thanks

Comment: this is a typo question. You cannot rely on an HTML markup tag as an input. Use an actual "input".

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner even when the form is isset ican get its value

Comment: most likely because you're (probably) using a GET array to get this `href='cart.php?id` elsewhere.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner it's a shopping cart ! so i when the user puts his desired quantity and saves on clicking on the update quantity button , i redirect him to the same page and i pass the command id and i get the new quantity updated by the user using $_POST so i can update it in the database , any solutions please idk if u are understanding me ? , thanks a lot

Comment: The form action should be the script processing the form.

Comment: you're going to have to post more code for this. You also have to rethink it all. If you're redirecting to the same page, there are other ways to do this. But, it's far too broad for me to code it.

Comment: What's the status of this question? @JayBlanchard provided you with an answer which to me, appears to be a/the solution. It should be marked as solved if it has. Seems to be the case here.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use an anchor tag as a portion of the form, as you've done here:

```
<a type="submit" name="updateu" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Update" class="btn btn-primary" href='cart.php?id=<?php echo $getid ?>&upt=<?php echo $row['idproduit']; ?>' ><i class="fa fa-clone"></i></a>
```

The link never becomes part of the post array. You will need a submit input named `updateu`, for example:

```
<input type="submit" name="updateu" ...
```

Comment: i can get it's value when a tag becomes a submit ! but i have to redirect the user to the href in the anchor tag !

Comment: You do that in the PHP script processing the request, not in the link.